# How can I find out the location of my (localdb) SQL Server 2012 database and back it up?

Tags: sql-server

I am using VS2012 and I have a database created:

```
(localdb)\v11.0 (SQL Server 11.0.2100 - T61\Alan)
```

How can I find out the physical location of this database. How can I back this up? Can I just make a copy of the files, move these to another location and start the database again.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="DB1Context" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
    , @DB_NAME NVARCHAR(100) = 'AdventureWorks2008R2'

SELECT TOP 1 @SQL = '
    BACKUP DATABASE [' + @DB_NAME + '] 
    TO DISK = ''' + REPLACE(mf.physical_name, '.mdf', '.bak') + ''''
FROM sys.master_files mf
WHERE mf.[type] = 0
    AND mf.database_id = DB_ID(@DB_NAME)

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output -

```
BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2008R2] 
TO DISK = 'D:\DATABASE\SQL2012\AdventureWorks2008R2.bak'
```

Answer (score 54):

It is quite confusing for people who touch with Entity Framework the first time.

If you use **Code First**, an mdf file is generated at `%USERPROFILE%` (e.g. `C:\Users\<username>`).

If you use **Database First**, you create a database under SQL Server Object Explorer (not Server Explorer!), an mdf file will be generated at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB`.

Comment: `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: I have 4 .mdf files in the this folder, master.mdf, model.mdf, and msdbdata.md and tempdb.mdf - not confusing at all ;-)

Comment: yes confusing.  which among these file have my data? also how to open MDF file using SQL management studio ?

Answer (score 51):

By default, LocalDB database creates “*.mdf” files in the C:/Users/"username" directory.

Link ref: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql.html

Answer (score 38):

In **SQL Server Management Studio**, `Right click on DataBase -> Properties -> Files` will tell you where on your hard disk it lives. If you backup the mdf, be sure to back up the ldf too.

[image]

Alternatively, you can right click on the DB, and choose `Tasks -> Backup`. This will make a a single .bak file for you, and you don't need to worry about the mdf/ldf.

Comment: To you want to connect to the LocalDB in  SQL Server Management Studio you have to use "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb" as Servername.

Answer (score 15):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

> The system database files for the database are stored in the users'
>   local AppData path which is normally hidden. For example
>   C:\Users\--user--\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
>   DB\Instances\LocalDBApp1. User database files are stored where the
>   user designates, typically somewhere in the C:\Users\\Documents\
>   folder.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to move the database then can I just move the files to another machine and start again?

Answer (score 3):

Open Windows registry editor and navigate to key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions`. Look beneath the **version key** of the SQL Server instance being targeted e.g. `11.0` for SQL 2012, and see its `InstanceAPIPath` value for file system location of the localdb's.

Note that at full list of SQL server versions mapped to release name and year can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#History)

Comment: Thank you. As far as I'm concerned, this should now be the selected answer.  For newbies, maybe should mention to use regedit in the command line to access the registry.

Comment: It points to the location of SqlUserInstance.dll file. How does this help?

Answer (score 3):

This PowerShell script, will give you the default location for localdb .mdf files:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
(New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(localdb)\$instancename")).DefaultFile
```

where `$instancename` is the name of the localdb instance you want to check for. You can get a list of localdb instances by running

```
sqllocaldb i
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything here and could not find them anywhere. I finally found them by searching *.mdf in file explorer. They were in `C:\Users\user\source\repos\CallNote\App_Data`.