# Where did Entity Framework 6.1 put my database?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, localdb

I am using EF 6.1 and VS 2012 to create a Code First data model basically following the Code First module in Julie Lehrman's EF5 Pluralsight video.  It appears to be working just as advertised except I can't find the data file anywhere.  I can access it in code, but by no other method.

I am using the LocalDb default connection factory.  The database does not appear in the Sql Server Object Explorer under (localdb)v/11.0.  There is no mdf file anywhere in the solution or my user folder. Where did Entity Framework put the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out the location of my (localdb) SQL Server 2012 database and back it up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202383/how-can-i-find-out-the-location-of-my-localdb-sql-server-2012-database-and-bac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalDb databases have a default location (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0), and you can open MSSQL Management Studio against them with the connection string "(localdb)\v11.0" and Windows authentication.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe looking at the connection string in the debugger will help you find it. Take a look at the Database.Connection.ConnectionString property of the Context you new up.

EF generates a different default connection string depending on the context it's ran in, so I can't tell you for sure where it'll be.

The relevant source code for generating the localdb connection string is [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/LocalDbConnectionFactory.cs)