# I can't find my SQL Server database after formatting my disk

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on a C# application using Entity Framework where I query a SQL Server database in two modes (manual / automatic). I used a code-first approach with an existing database.

The manual mode was working and I started working on the automatic mode. My computer needed formatting, so I took a copy of my project (it was on `D:\`). After the format I reinstalled Visual Studio and resumed working on another path in my project.

Checking the SQL Server Object Explorer I didn't find my database tables I previously had

[SQL_ServerObjectExplorer][image: 1].

I tried refreshing but same result.

So, where did my database tables go?

Comment: have you installed sql server?

Comment: You say that you "took a copy of my project", what exactly does this mean?  Can you look into this copy and see if your SqlServer .mdf and .ldf files are there?

Comment: If you took a backup....did you restore that backup in SQL Server?

Comment: Did you copy your code but not your database?

Comment: You have to Attached the database back to the server. In SQL Server Management Studio you can right click Database and add.  If you have a current database you can change properties of the file location to your d drive.

Comment: I think that the database no longer exists

Comment: What steps did you take to back up your database prior to formatting? SQL Server is a separate product with a separate installation and a separate data store location from your application code and binaries. If you didn't back up the database, chances are high that the database is gone.

Comment: as far as i can see, your DB is gone, if you want to recover your database you should try using a recovery tool, somthing like getdataback, recuba or any other tool. stop using the pc and install the disk in another pc to better chances of recovery.

Comment: Code-first  so the database structure can be restored by your app. The data is gone however. You may need to create an empty database first and point your app to it

Comment: I guess you lost your LocalDB installation with that wipeout... next time make sure you back it up as explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18202680/1534753

Answer (score 0):

The database exists at all most likely because your application code creates a default database when one is not found. This is the default implementation for EF Code First with Migrations enabled.

> So, where did my database tables go?

Reformatting cleared everything, but it looks like your code doesn't have the necessary migration steps configured to create the needed tables, or your migration strategy is not setup to automatically upgrade to the latest version.

> Another issue that is harder to notice the first time, if migrations are not managed carefully, especially at the start of a project or when this is your first *Code-First* project, if there is a SQL or other *Exception* raised during migration executions, then the migrations will no be executed.

I would first try to run the following command in the package manager console:

```
update-database
```

Simple I know... If you have automatic migrations enabled in the code, but you don't handle the exceptions that are raised, then it will just look to the user as if the app didn't load. So execute the migrations from within VS and inspect the output.

If there are no migrations to apply, then either there are no migrations in your code to actually apply, which might mean that you were managing the database schema manually or via another technique, or something else has gone wrong with configuration, this is entirely subjective to your specific project environment, and way out of scope for an SO post.

However... You could short-circuit all that and run the following to try and generate a new migration to take you from zero, to where your coded schema is now:

```
add-migration AfterFormat
```

If this generates a new migration script that is empty, then there are no changes, if this is the case, then you are simply using the wrong connection string or there are no tables defined in your EF DbContext...