# Cannot connect to localDB SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I get this error when trying to access my local db
[image]

Yesterday everything was ok. I closed everything just like always and now I get this. I'm also not able to locate my folder where sql saves my databases and when I run my api project from visual studio and try to get some data using swagger I get only 204, I configured it so when there is no data to sent back to send a 204, so its just like there my database was deleted

Comment: When you write "locate my folder where sql saves my databases," do you mean that you know where the database file was? If not, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41689006/1115360) gives the two likely locations. Otherwise, can you restore from a backup?

Comment: `.` at the beginning of the server name is a mistake. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the commnets, now I found my database and also the point in the server name was the problem